# TAB command and \caption

Tags: tables, captions

Is there a way to add a description to this collection of cells?

Something like `\caption` command. I tried but to no avail

```
\begin{TAB}(e){|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
t & e & s & t & 0 & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
\end{TAB}
```

While using \table, for example, I can add a descrition:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Bla Bla Bla}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `table` environment can contain *anything*, not just a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Bla Bla Bla}
\centering
\medskip
\begin{TAB}(e){|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
t & e & s & t & 0 & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
\end{TAB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I used `\centering` instead of the `center` environment and a `\medskip` to separate the caption from the table. Also I added some placement specifiers (`h` should never be used alone).

[image]

Comment: @g9999 Since this helped you, please consider marking this as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below egreg's vote count.